# Loop for cleaning dataset (R)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-science

I am a beginner data scientist working within an NCAA football program. We record repeated measures data during practice that needs to be organized then analyzed. I have this sample dataset that I am having trouble analyzing due to the variations/typos in the "Activity" column. I need a way to rename/organize the activities in the dataframe.

Raw Dataset looks like this:

| Position | Activity | Max_Velocity (mph) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WR | Special Team 1 | 20 |
| WR | special team 1 | 19 |
| WR | Special team 1 | 18 |
| WR | special Team 2 | 13 |
| WR | ST 2 | 16 |
| WR | St 2 | 19 |
| WR | team 1 | 12 |
| WR | team 1 | 20 |
| WR | team 1 | 23 |
| WR | team 2 | 21 |
| WR | team 2 | 10 |
| WR | team 2 | 3 |
| WR | team 3 | 21 |
| WR | team 3 | 11 |
| WR | team 3 | 16 |
| WR | Indy 1 | 20 |
| WR | indy 2 | 21 |
| WR | INDY 3 | 22 |

I need it to look like this:

| Position | Activity | Max_Velocity (mph) | Activity_Catagory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WR | Special Team 1 | 20 | Special Team |
| WR | special team 1 | 19 | Special Team |
| WR | Special team 1 | 18 | Special Team |
| WR | special Team 2 | 13 | Special Team |
| WR | ST 2 | 16 | Special Team |
| WR | St 2 | 19 | Special Team |
| WR | team 1 | 12 | Team |
| WR | team 1 | 20 | Team |
| WR | team 1 | 23 | Team |
| WR | team 2 | 21 | Team |
| WR | team 2 | 10 | Team |
| WR | team 2 | 3 | Team |
| WR | team 3 | 21 | Team |
| WR | team 3 | 11 | Team |
| WR | team 3 | 16 | Team |
| WR | Indy 1 | 20 | Indy |
| WR | indy 2 | 21 | Indy |
| WR | INDY 3 | 22 | Indy |

This way I can analyze the average of the dependent variable "Max_velocity" during each type of activity. I would rather not make individual lines of code correcting each typo in the "Activity" column. I think this can be done with loops but I am a beginner and don't know where to start. I would greatly appreciate any help to make this a simple fix.

Comment: should not be `indy1` row have `indy`  instead of `team`??

Comment: you need to create set of rules. if you are having more than 1 word. then take their initial and combine them. Special Team --> ST. You need to create a dictionary to map the words. and also use regex to capture only words (not the digits)

Comment: Can you show that with code? I am unfamiliar with regex

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: So I need to create a dictionary to link "activity typos" to the output I want. I don't understand regex though. Is that a function, library, etc?

Comment: pandas str has that functionality. You are trying to capture the pattern: `( words before space and digit)`

Comment: @Mark Among regex stands for [regular expression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), is it a pattern matching language that is widely used to perform operations on text.

Comment: Any reason why the `python` tag has been changed to `R`?

Comment: Even if you are doing in R, logic will remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

**try:**

In first step, I am using regex to capture the text before appearance of digit. see: https://regex101.com/r/8xTxPl/1
Then I am trying to capitallize the 1st letter of the words.
last is to map the short form with the full form.

```
actv = (df1.Activity.str.extract('([\w\s]+)\s\d', expand=False).str.title())
df1 = df1.assign(new_Actv = np.where(actv=='St', 'Special Team', actv))
```

**df1:**

|  | Position | Activity | Max_Velocity (mph) | new_Actv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | WR | Special Team 1 | 20 | Special Team |
| 1 | WR | special team 1 | 19 | Special Team |
| 2 | WR | Special team 1 | 18 | Special Team |
| 3 | WR | special Team 2 | 13 | Special Team |
| 4 | WR | ST 2 | 16 | Special Team |
| 5 | WR | St 2 | 19 | Special Team |
| 6 | WR | team 1 | 12 | Team |
| 7 | WR | team 1 | 20 | Team |
| 8 | WR | team 1 | 23 | Team |
| 9 | WR | team 2 | 21 | Team |
| 10 | WR | team 2 | 10 | Team |
| 11 | WR | team 2 | 3 | Team |
| 12 | WR | team 3 | 21 | Team |
| 13 | WR | team 3 | 11 | Team |
| 14 | WR | team 3 | 16 | Team |
| 15 | WR | Indy 1 | 20 | Indy |
| 16 | WR | indy 2 | 21 | Indy |
| 17 | WR | INDY 3 | 22 | Indy |

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can you expand upon the code you used?

Comment: @MarkMamon: Do you want explanation?

Comment: yes I would like a lengthy detailed explaination. I am a beginner so I need it to be thoroughly explained.

Comment: @MarkMamon: That regex part you can explain it better from that link :)   `[\w\s]+` ==>capturing the `text containing words or space more than 1 times`. so it will capture the whole text. now I have put the restrictions. NO!! I want the `text before space followed by the digit`. so it will give you `Special Team`

Answer (score 2):

With this solution you can use arbitrary keywords and custom patterns:

```
categ = (df.Activity.str.extract('(?P<SpecialTeam>special team|st)|(?P<Team>team)|(?P<Indy>indy)', flags=2)
                    .notnull()
        )
df['Activity_Category'] = categ[categ].stack().reset_index()['level_1']
```

This defines a [regex with grouped names](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) of the form `'(?P<group1_name>pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)|(?P<group2_name>pattern1|…)'`

`flags=2` is equivalent to `flags=re.IGNORECASE` and makes the matches case insensitive

You get a dataframe `categ` with one column per group and True/False

```
    SpecialTeam   Team   Indy
0          True  False  False
1          True  False  False
…
6         False   True  False
…
17        False  False   True
```

It is then stacked to keep only the `True` values, that are the categories names.

output:

```
   Position         Activity  Max_Velocity (mph) Activity_Category
0       WR   Special Team 1                   20       SpecialTeam
1       WR   special team 1                   19       SpecialTeam
2       WR   Special team 1                   18       SpecialTeam
3       WR   special Team 2                   13       SpecialTeam
4       WR             ST 2                   16       SpecialTeam
5       WR             St 2                   19       SpecialTeam
6       WR           team 1                   12              Team
7       WR           team 1                   20              Team
8       WR           team 1                   23              Team
9       WR           team 2                   21              Team
10      WR           team 2                   10              Team
11      WR           team 2                    3              Team
12      WR           team 3                   21              Team
13      WR           team 3                   11              Team
14      WR           team 3                   16              Team
15      WR           Indy 1                   20              Indy
16      WR           indy 2                   21              Indy
17      WR           INDY 3                   22              Indy
```

One limitation is that you cannot use spaces in regex group names, but if you use CamelCase, you can fix it with:

```
df['Activity_Category'] = df.Activity_Category.apply(lambda s: re.sub('([a-z])([A-Z])','\g<1> \g<2>', s))
```

Comment: Learned something new. Advanced Regex :OOO +1. Never thought stack can be used in this problem :O

Comment: Well, to be honest, I had never done it, just thought of it now ;)